# Get latest commit in branch x which is also in branch y

Tags: git

I am looking for a CLI command to achieve the following:

```
Get latest commit in branch x which is also in branch y
```

I googled around and found this:

> git diff -u <(git rev-list --first-parent origin/feature/x) <(git rev-list --first-parent origin/feature/y) | sed -ne 's/^ //p' | head -1

Unfortunately, this doesn't work on my server on an alpine image and it seems super complicated. That's why I'm looking for a new solution.

Thx!

Comment: You have to define *latest* rather carefully here, but [Romain Valeri's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70850896/1256452) is probably the one you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to use

`git merge-base <commit-ish> <commit-ish>`
([doc for git merge-base](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-base))

which outputs the hash of the most recent common ancestor.

Note that `<commit-ish>` here can be a commit hash as well as a branch name, see [the definition here](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#Documentation/gitglossary.txt-aiddefcommit-ishacommit-ishalsocommittish).

Comment: Sounds good but I need the commit and have the branch. How would I use it?

Comment: You're right, I forgot to say you could use branch names. Edited!

Comment: git merge-base --fork-point <branch> looks promising?

Comment: @Ron Indeed. Be sure to compare the different modes.

Comment: Note that `--fork-point` has a very different use case, and depends on reflogs: it will give the wrong answer in general (but the right answer in the specific use case, which is when doing some particular kinds of rebase, but not other kinds of rebase!).

Comment: Ok... I gave it a shot and it seems to work.